# How to convert XML files to tensors in PyTorch?

Tags: python, xml, machine-learning, pytorch

I am working with OhioT1DM dataset. the structure looks like this:

```
dataset/
    ├── 2018/
    │   ├── train/
    │   │   ├── data1.xml
    │   │   ├── data2.xml
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └── test/
    │       ├── data1.xml
    │       ├── data2.xml
    │       └── ...
    └── 2020/
        ├── train/
        │   ├── data1.xml
        │   ├── data2.xml
        │   └── ...
        └── test/
            ├── data1.xml
            ├── data2.xml
            └── ...
```

I want to parse the XML data using ElementTree and feed them into my model. I want the combination of both 2018 and 2020 data.

For each XML file, the root consists of several children, each child has a different attribute (no text, just attrib). for example:

```
<patient id="552" weight="99" insulin_type="Humalog">

 <temp_basal>
     <event ts_begin="03-07-2027 22:14:24" ts_end="03-07-2027 
 22:31:50" value="0.0"/>
     <event ts_begin="27-05-2025 05:39:51" ts_end="27-05-2025 
 08:02:20" value="0.0"/>
      ...
 </temp_basal>
 ...
 <meal>
     <event ts="04-07-2027 17:47:00" type="Dinner" carbs="120"/>
     <event ts="05-06-2025 13:00:00" type="Snack" carbs="35"/>
     ...
 </meal>
 ...
</patient>
```

I want to convert XML data into tensors and feed them into my model.
How can I do it?

Comment: Put it through Pandas via https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_xml.html ; then to Numpy is one more function call

Comment: You have different time stamps, one times begin and end in the other only one, how should this matched?

Comment: I defined a sliding window in my code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer to my question, I used Pandas to convert them into csv files:

```
# Parse the XML file
xml_file_path = '/content/OhioT1DM/train/540-ws-training.xml'
tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
root = tree.getroot()
# Extract the base file name (without extension) from the XML file path
base_file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(xml_file_path))[0]

# Initialize variables
meal_data = []
temp_basal_data = []
.....


# Iterate through the temp_basal elements and extract values
for event in root.findall(".//temp_basal/event"):
    timestamp_begin = event.get('ts_begin')
    timestamp_end = event.get('ts_end')
    temp_basal_value = event.get('value')
    temp_basal_data.append({'temp_basal_ts_begin': timestamp_begin,'temp_basal_ts_end': timestamp_end,'temp_basal_value': temp_basal_value})

# Iterate through the meal elements and extract values
for event in root.findall(".//meal/event"):
    timestamp = event.get('ts')
    meal_type = event.get('type')
    meal_carbs = event.get('carbs')
    meal_data.append({'meal_timestamp': timestamp, 'meal_type': meal_type, 'meal_carbs': meal_carbs })
....

# Create a DataFrame from the data
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Generate the CSV file name using the base file name
csv_file_path = f'{base_file_name}.csv'

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file 
df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False)
```